# Is "segmentation fault" caused from fopen line a stack overflow problem in C? (darknet, detector.c)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen, darknet

I am experiencing a darknet YOLOv4. I want to add detection result logging line to this mAP example code.
I think I wrote a line that writes files according to the grammar, but the "segmentation fault" error occurs in the line where "fopen" is operated.
The line like printf works well.

The validate_detector_map() part of the detector.c of darknet is attached below.

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/detector.c#L940

And below is the part I added.(////ju added~ //////////)

```
...    // For multi-class precision and recall computation
float *avg_iou_per_class = (float*)xcalloc(classes, sizeof(float));
int *tp_for_thresh_per_class = (int*)xcalloc(classes, sizeof(int));
int *fp_for_thresh_per_class = (int*)xcalloc(classes, sizeof(int));

for (t = 0; t < nthreads; ++t) {
    args.path = paths[i + t];
    args.im = &buf[t];
    args.resized = &buf_resized[t];
    thr[t] = load_data_in_thread(args);
}

////ju added //파일 열려야 하는 위치
printf("\nlogging start.. \n\n");

FILE *log_csv;
printf('%d\n', fileno(log_csv));
if(!(fopen("/home/aicar/darknet/0_log_ju0.csv", 'a')))
{
    printf("failed to open csv file\n\n");
    exit(1);
    
}
else
{
    printf("csv file opened\n\n");
    fprintf(log_csv, "timestamp, class_id, gt, conf_mat, \n" ); //header row
    fclose(log_csv);
}
//////////
time_t start = time(0);

for (i = nthreads; i < m + nthreads; i += nthreads) { ......
```

Is this a stack overflow problem? The reason I thought that was because the author used the free function.

Comment: The 2nd argument to `fopen` is a string, not a `char`: `fopen("/home/aicar/darknet/0_log_ju0.csv", 'a')` --> `fopen("/home/aicar/darknet/0_log_ju0.csv", "a")`. Use double quotes, `"a"`.

Comment: Didn't you get at least compiler warnings? Compile with `-Wall` and `Wextra`.

Comment: @Jue: Do you by any chance come with a Python programming background? I see that you've used single quotes `'` for things that are supposed to be strings. In C `"` and `'` are not interchangeable with respect to strings. `'…'` denotes a single character (possibly a compiler extension multibyte character), whereas `"…"` denotes a string literal that can be used to initialize a `char …[]` array, or as a immutable pointer to a read only string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fopen` returns a file handle. Just a couple lines above you're defining a variable `FILE *log_csv;` which would be probably where you want to put that handle.

Furthermore the second argument of `fopen` is a C-string (i.e. a pointer to a NUL terminated array of chars). TTBT, I'm surprised your compiler did let this pass.

Try this:

```
FILE *log_csv = fopen("/home/aicar/darknet/0_log_ju0.csv", "a");
if( !log_csv ){
    printf("failed to open csv file\n\n");
    exit(1);
} else {
    printf("%d\n", fileno(log_csv));
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is also dangerous:

```
FILE *log_csv;
printf('%d\n', fileno(log_csv));
```

The `fileno()` function will attempt to dereference `log_csv`, which does not point to a `FILE` structure and therefore extremely likely to cause a `SIGSEGV` crash.

Comment: This is not only dangerous but it's blatantly wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Well, it's syntactically correct, which is why a refrained from using stronger language in my answer.  But yeah, it's FUBAR.

Comment: Well, dereferencing an obvious null pointer is also syntactically correct, but it's also worse than "dangerous".